# Programmatically set height of specific line in ReportBuilder

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

**Disclaimer**: I'm not a Delphi programmer, and I'm doing this because this is an old project that needs some minor tweaking (and, since 2018, my workplace no longer has a Delphi programmer).

Is it possible to use the Calc tab inside ReportBuilder to set the height of a specific line inside a Memo field? I've no idea if this is possible from the Design view / tab.

To put it simply, I want to increase the spacing / padding between the two last lines (like in, say OpenOffice / LibreOffice Writer, or Microsoft Word, etc).

This is what I have right now inside `BeforePrint` event. `Memo1` and `Memo2` are two mutually unrelated memo fields.

```
procedure ReportBeforePrint;
begin
    Memo1.lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Variable1.Caption);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Variable2.Caption + ' ' + Variable5.Caption);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Variable3.Caption);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Variable4.Caption);
    
    Memo2.lines.Clear;   
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Variable6.Caption);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Variable7.Caption);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Variable8.Caption);
// the code below does nothing
    Variable9.Height := 1.2;
    Variable10.Height := 1.2;
// the code above does nothing
    Memo2.Lines.Add('stuff:' + Variable9.Caption + ' moreStuff: ' + Variable10.Caption);
end;
```

Is there a way for me to set the height of a specific line? In this case, I'd like to be able to set the height of the last line inside Memo2, leaving all of the others to their default value. Something along the lines of:

```
procedure ReportBeforePrint;
begin
// rest of the code....
    Memo2.Lines.Add('stuff:' + Variable9.Caption + ' moreStuff: ' + Variable10.Caption);
    Memo2.LastLine.Height := 1.2;
end;
```

I've also tried changing the height and font values of Variable9 and Variable10, inside of Design tab > Properties > Text > Font, but that did nothing.

I am aware that I could make empty variables and make another line with them, but I don't want to do that.

**EDIT**
This is what I'm hoping to get (row 4).

[image]

Comment: I'm not used to the ReportBuilder but I doubt it is related to that at all: you adding plain text to the Memo (such as `Anything.Caption` only has text and is unbound to whatever `Anything.Height` contains). A Memo is nothing more than multiline text, where formattings affect anything. Which is WinApi knowledge and unbound to Delphi. What you want can be achieved thru RichEdit.

Comment: Have you tried adding a blank line? Memo1.lines.add('');

Comment: @AmigoJack Unfortunately, I can not use RichEdit here.

Comment: @FLDelphi I have, but it seems a crude solution, as I can not fine tune it to a specific height (for example 1.2, or 1.5 lines), while keeping the line height of other lines at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that I'm an idiot. Ended up creating `Memo3` below `Memo2`, and changing the spacing between them, and also setting a smaller font for the contents of `Memo3`.

Apologies for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: You live up to your name then.